# Baudrate calculation

Tags: serial, uart, baudrate

I am having a hard time to calculate the baud rate for the following:

Needed baud rate for 2 bytes data at 1KHz over an UART port with a 8N1 protocol

Thanks

Comment: what is *" 2 bytes data at 1KHz "* ? Do you mean you need to transmit 2 bytes of data every millisecond?

Answer (score 1):

2 bytes at 1kHz at 10 bits per byte = 1,000 * 2 * 10 = 20 kbit/second

So your minimum, standard, baud rate would be 38,400.